# SQL - Sum Top N values in each row

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, top-n

This is my SQL table.

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| name  | q1   | q2   | q3   | q4   |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| Alex  |    5 |    4 |   10 |    7 |
| Brown |    7 |    6 |    4 |    1 |
| Chris |   10 |   10 |    9 |   10 |
| Dave  |    8 |    4 |    6 |    0 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

I'd like to sum the top 2 scores from each user in my SQL query above.

For example, the top 2 scores of Alex are `10` and `7`, and so the sum is `10 + 7 = 17`

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT NewStudents.name, SUM(q1+q2+q3+q4) FROM NewStudents 
GROUP BY NewStudents.name;
```

To sum all `q1, q2, q3, q4` but this query sums all `q1` to `q4`, not the top 2 scores among `q1` to `q4`.

How can I construct the statement that I want to do in mySQL?

Comment: Your data structure makes what you want very difficult to accomplish, since sql is optimized to work across records, not within one. You should really change your data structure.

Comment: Consider revising your design. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 2):

As stated in @Shadow in comment.. Your database need restructure again.. Because that's not database work.. You can restructure and make design like this..

```
+-------+----+--------+
| name  |  q | point  |
+-------+----+--------+
| Alex  |  1 |      5 |
| Alex  |  2 |      4 |
| Alex  |  3 |     10 |
| Alex  |  4 |      7 |
| Brown |  1 |      7 |
| Brown |  2 |      6 |
| Brown |  3 |      4 |
| Brown |  4 |      1 |
| Chris |  1 |     10 |
| Chris |  2 |     10 |
| Chris |  3 |      9 |
| Chris |  4 |     10 |
| Dave  |  1 |      8 |
| Dave  |  2 |      4 |
| Dave  |  3 |      6 |
| Dave  |  4 |      0 |
+-------+----+--------+
```

And for the query you can do like this:

```
select
     name, sum(point)
from(
     select 
          name, q, point,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY point DESC) as ranked
     from newstudents) rankedSD
where
     ranked in (1,2)
group by 
     name
```

You can check the demo here:

[**Demo<>Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e6117ff9e63f7a793376f71a01be146)

Edit : You can use `Window Function`. You can read [*Row_Number() Function*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)

Answer (score 1):

A normalised design might look like this:

```
name q score
Alex  1  5
Alex 2  4
Alex 3 10
Alex 4  7
```

Answer (score -1):

In older versions of MySQL, you can use variables for this purpose:

```
select name, sum(q)
from (select nq.*,
             (@rn := if(@n = name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@n := name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select nq.*
            from ((select name, q1 as q from t
                  ) union all
                  (select name, q2 as q from t
                  ) union all
                  (select name, q3 as q from t
                  ) union all
                  (select name, q4 as q from t
                  )
                 ) nq
            order by name, q desc
           ) nq cross join
           (select @n := '', @rn := 0) params
      ) nq
where rn <= 2;
```